# htaccess redirects to http instead of https

Tags: .htaccess

I've set a redirect rule in htaccess - but instead of redirecting the url to the right scheme (https) it first redirect to http. 
for example:

```
RewriteRule ^prefixurl/(aaa|bbb|ccc)/suffixurl$ prefixurl/ddd/suffixurl [R=301,QSA,L]
```

What happens is 
I get from :

> https://www.example.com/prefixurl/bbb/suffixurl

--> (redirects to)

> http://www.example.com/prefixurl/ddd/suffixurl

--> (2nd redirect to)

> https://www.example.com/prefixurl/ddd/suffixurl

(there is nginx server in front of Apache with directive to move all non https back to https...)

Why the redirect to http takes place ? any way to fix it ?

Comment: you mean https://%{HTTP_HOST} ?

Comment: yes that was a typo I meant `RewriteRule ^prefixurl/(aaa|bbb|ccc)/suffixurl$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/prefixurl/ddd/suffixurl [R=301,NC,L]`

Comment: you got it right !! thanks - you can post it is an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this single rule to get your redirect and get `https://` in redirected URL:

```
RewriteRule ^prefixurl/(aaa|bbb|ccc)/suffixurl$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/prefixurl/ddd/suffixurl [R=301,NC,L]
```